# Load a class from Maven dependency using a classloader

Tags: java, maven, classloader

I have a Maven project and I want  to use a class from my dependency. I want to load it in my code through a class loader. Is there a way to load a class that is part of a dependency?

Comment: Why try to load via classloader? If you have defined it as dependency it's already on the classpath?

Comment: maven dependencies are automatically added to classpath. You can try importing your class after adding your dependency

Comment: he want to use or to check something from the classloader, it should work but actually on;y current project classes are in classloader